# Access google nest camera streaming with google api

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, nest-device-access

I want to access the live streaming of my Google nest camera using the [Google Apis](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream?hl=en).

So far I've managed to:

1. Register into [Device Access Console](https://console.nest.google.com/device-access)
2. Create a project inside the Google console

I was able to obtain authorization following the [guide](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize?hl=en) but, this is not how I want to gain access.

Is it not possibile to create a service account that authenticates without following the OAuth consent screen?

I tried to do this with a small js code using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#service-account-credentials) npm package

```js
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service'];
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './key.json',
    scopes
});

const client = await auth.getClient();
google.options({ auth: client });

const sdm = google.smartdevicemanagement({
    version: 'v1'
});
```

But it keep telling me that the enterprise id is not found.
It seems to me that the service account is not linked to "Device access console".

I tried also to give `Google Home Developer Console Admin` role to the service account.

Is there a way to link the service account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are accessing first party cameras that belong to users we designed the 3P access flow by requiring the OAuth screen to be shown to the users in order to access Google devices with device access APIs by needing the tokens for the OAuth flow.

It's not possible to access using service accounts.

Comment: If i retrieve the authorization code from the oauth flow, can I reuse it multiple times? How long does the authorization code last? This duration changes if i apply for commercial development? Thanks